# base64 decoded string gives weird chars

Tags: encryption, base64

eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYXV0aC5zbmFwY2hhdC5jb21cL3NuYXBfdG9rZW5cL3Rva2VuIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIiwiZW5jIjoiQTEyOENCQy1IUzI1NiIsImFsZyI6ImRpciIsImtpZCI6InNuYXAtYWNjZXNzLXRva2VuLWExMjhjYmMtaHMyNTYuMCJ9..mpqjrn8IPdzqrQC0VhJwMA.JJN9Rrc1k_qh1Iq-jGS-1754-iI_L5mISH7mHix5WCIXx4wqkQz3z8o9nDcBRUJijioV_EMFYW9OayWGHaFR5NlG0ROKHfkJPPWSz4Y47jyZwQxKjEQDMCdPi9HcpNJM_ao6umAQj3gdfFqGK8M9e2_oYy-q6bR6UzeqFvQVLt599KLwl2yJhevgLRFBs7kLd5NG8ZsKGNhTwWs7zYPPZFutyhOmPY13zt1hJsSwek1UXRRZm8qZEEQZsmSbuSQ0sAMvyIh9uZyMCEwdMfo6pU31cnya29Pi_vHJP_TLHH0PNgddOPzpp911Yp4c1lfEY99C3dknQ5DJFtkfdaA3MAUrqKj8NAsIcrX8qPrxpVhDgZ2tqqrkgQb6EMoxEIdRGssIRdR5_jL-F8_8xfhNxIM3mv1NEPkSPIBfOsbSRbBGPecCUwmaB-yP9OmPEyUWv0ieQkGKp5B1J6cFykrMlpmmGkB7H9WIwuDNM4IPLBBBaLgGegIBdwrTU22Yv7Qn2RXKpDObPRuSghUmIvLpr_LwGZ78N4YW-G-nTw_EOjlD58UDHOuth_EcKszBeLs0_EIe9JZzykjulg3ffROHI-

This is a token. when base64 decoded it gives some valid output but then it starts printing weird chars. Is this really only b64 or is their even a way to tell. I stripped some of the chars out for obvious reasons.

Comment: Note that just stripping out characters does not protect any data that you've displayed on screen, it's very easy to decode the various scraps left.

Answer (score 0):

It's not base 64 encoded, it is [base 64 URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5) encoded. Replace the `-` with a `+` and the `_` (underscore) with the `/` character, then pad with `=` characters until you have a multiple of 4 base 64 characters (not counting whitespace). Then decode and the result should be correct. If not, the base 64 URL code was probably damaged.

I presume you have stripped off the characters and replaced them by a dot, because dots should not be present in URL-safe base 64.

---

Of course finding and using a base64url decoder would be more efficient than the generic find/replace/append scheme mentioned here.

Comment: what do you mean pad

Comment: Well, pad is just add to the left or right to a certain size. In this case you have to append the characters at the right. I've added a link to the RFC that specifies these encodings.